# NodeJS + Express served HTML file not loading js file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am running a NodeJS server which uses a catchall route to serve a file 'index.html'.  In that file, I am linking to a javascript file in the same directory.  That javascript file is not being correctly loaded.  The error in my console reads 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <', which after researching seems to mean that the path to my JS file is incorrect.  However, the js file is located in the same directory as 'index.html', and I am referencing it like so  which should be correct?

Here is my code

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('./app/models/User');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var path = require('path');

//Set the public folder
app.use(express.static('/public'));

//Allows us to parse POST data.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(config.db);

var apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

//MEAN apps use a catchall after any routes created by Node.

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(1337);

console.log('Server started at ' + Date());
```

**public/app/views/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <h1>Served by node + express.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**public/app/views/test.js**

```
console.log('test.js loaded');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`?

Comment: This was the problem thank you!  Just the missing __dirname.  Obviously I'm a noob with express :(  Just started learning it a week ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657829/css-file-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff this help me out in resolving `MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)` error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should set your static folder like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Also, your html file will look inside the /public folder itself for your script file. You'll need to give your index.html file the right path to your script file.

```
<script src="/app/views/test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's what's happening:

- The browser requests `/`, which is responded to by your catchall route, so it gets back `index.html`.
- The browser then sees a script in the html at `./test.js`, so the browser then interprets that as `/test.js` and makes a request for that. The `express.static` middleware looks up `public/test.js`, which does not exist, so it passes execution to the next defined route that matches the request, which is your catchall route. This means html is sent for the javascript file, hence the error that you see.

So to fix this, you need to change `./test.js` to the actual relative path (`./app/views/test.js`) or use an absolute path (`/app/views/test.js`) to make sure the correct path is always used, no matter what the current path is.

Additionally, you will need to change this:

```
app.use(express.static('/public'));
```

to something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Otherwise the `express.static` middleware will look for a directory named `public` off the root of your filesystem and you will have the same problem with the catchall route serving html for your javascript file request.

Comment: Hi, I just tried that and it didn't work.  I also tried "./app/views/test.js" just because.  Also didn't work.

Comment: The problem was the missing __dirname variable thanks.  Should I also be using path.join inside express.static?

Comment: I actually should mark this as the answer also, since changing the path to what you said and making the addition of the __dirname variable to express.static both combined to solve the problem.  :)  I really appreciate you taking the time to reply and help.

Comment: This answer helped me more than the others, because just changing the app.use didn't work, and also it explains what is going on and why we need to make those changes