# CSS file blocked: MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: css, node.js, angular, express, mime-types

I am developing an Angular 4 app and I want to apply some global styles.  Following the [tutorial at the angular site](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#global-application-styles), I've created a "styles.css" file in the root directory of my app, and I'm referring to that stylesheet in the index.html of my app:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

The angular app is successfully compiled:

```
$ ng serve 
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
[...]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I visit http://localhost:4200 in a Chromium browser, the console shows an error at

```
GET http://localhost:4200/styles.css
```

In a Firefox browser, the error is a bit more explicit:

```
GET 
http://localhost:4200/styles.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 15ms]
The resource from "http://localhost:4200/styles.css" was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Both files, index.html and styles.css are located in the root directory of my angular app. 
I've tried to get [more info about the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) :

```
nosniff
    Blocks a request if the requested type is

        "style" and the MIME type is not "text/css", or
        "script" and the MIME type is not a JavaScript MIME type.
```

But I don't understand why it's bloking the request, since I've specified `type="text/css"` when referencing the stylesheet.

Comment: What does it say the mimetype of `styles.css` is?

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to see the request and response headers. Verify the mime types are as you expect.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. It appears to be a quirk of [Express](https://expressjs.com/) that can manifest itself for a few different reasons, judging by the number of hits from searching the web for "nodejs express css mime type".

Despite the `type="text/css"` attribute we put in our `<link` elements, Express is returning the CSS file as

```
Content-Type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

whereas it really should be returning it as

```
Content-Type: "text/css"
```

For me, the quick and dirty workaround was to simply remove the `rel=` attribute, i.e., change

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

to

```html
<link type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Testing confirmed that the CSS file was downloaded and the styles did actually work, and that was good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I can confirm this. I updated `Express` and ran into the same problem. Remove the `rel` attribute fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't think this is good advice, removing `rel="stylesheet"` would make browser unaware of the file as a stylesheet and hence the styles will not be evaluated and applied

Comment: @benjaminz - It's certainly not an ideal solution but as I said, the styles did get applied, in my case anyway. A better solution would be to fix Express so it serves up the CSS files with the correct  MIME type.

Comment: I was working around this problem for a long time your answer helps me get through it thanks!

Comment: those stylesheets are added by angular cli, have no direct access to rel attribute

Comment: @GordThompson. Sir this was helpful. but I am also getting `Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).localhost:3000` for JS. Please help

Comment: I am not using any CSS file in my html file but only javascript file and I still get MIME type mismatch. So, I can't even try this answer to see if will help.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="styles.css">` for me doing this solved the error XD

Answer (score 23):

I also removed `rel = "stylesheet"`, and I no longer get the MIME type error, but the styles are not being loaded

Answer (score 20):

Some answers suggested removing rel="stylesheet", that didn't work out for me however.
According to the expressjs documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
use `express.static` function to serve static files such as CSS, JavaScript,etc...

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

and from there you should be able to load any file under the public directory
for example, if you have a style.css file inside the directory `{PROJECT_PATH}/public/css/`

`http://localhost:3000/css/style.css` will work.

Comment: The problem is not that OP cannot get the files. The path is correct, and the files are sent to the browser, but the MIME type is not matching.

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson That's right. I am having the same issue. For all the linked files, it keeps saying type mismatch.

Comment: @ThN This  happened like two years ago, but yes I'm aware that OP was getting the error due to type mismatch, but while I was looking for answers to my problem which was similar I tried the suggested solutions and still had an error so I shared what worked for me in case someone has a similar problem.

Answer (score 7):

In running into the same kind of issue for a full stack web application (in development), I simply solved the problem by correctly linking the css file to the page rendered. Removing the `rel = stylesheet`, as suggested above, prevents the error to show up in the browser but it does not load the styles that should be applied to the page. In short, it isn't a solution.

If you are using `express-static` you can use this as an example:

**Server-side:**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", {
    index: false, 
    immutable: true, 
    cacheControl: true,
    maxAge: "30d"
}));
```

**Client-side:**

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
```

Just add a forward slash in front of the file you wish to link to the html page (if you are rendering html pages without using any `template engines`) and express-static will do the rest automatically for you.

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem with a javascript file (as opposed to css) in an Angular app.  In reality, the problem wasn't with the Mime type (as the outer error message indicated) but was ultimately a "404 Not Found" error.

In my case, putting the script file anywhere but in the "assets" folder resulted in the 404 and eventually the mime type error.  The following tag worked for me in the head section of index.html:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The assets folder is a sibling of the Index.html file.

Comment: This was my problem too - after a path update, the src path was wrong. Why does the browser not put a 404 in the network tab? Weird!

Answer (score 7):

This is solved my problem:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Comment: This was the solution for me too - worth pointing out that you need to require path:

const path = require('path');

Answer (score 5):

A simple hack is to add a forward slash `/` before the the path to the stylesheet used. For me it was `href='css/style.css'`, changed it to `href='/css/style.css'`. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue.

I moved the script file to a different location and now there is no error:

from `<script src="./scripts/simple-keyboard/keyboard.index.min.js" type="text/html"></script>`
to `<script src="./scripts/keyboard.index.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

As noted by Davelli, the issue wasn't a file mismatch but an error not found. It's strange it returned the wrong error!

Comment: You need to have all the scripts and html files in the public folder, then outside the public folder will be the node file e.g. app.js. Make sure you are the type as "text/javascript" if it is a javascript file. You may also need to export it e.g. export module Test.js

Comment: Yep. Browser error message is very misleading. That's what got me all confused. I did what you said and Viola!!! it works... :) thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer useful ^

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just include "/" before "css/style.css"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

I also use express.static('public')

Answer (score 1):

if this solutions does not help:

```
 app.use(express.static('public'))//for server
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">//for styles
```

Then make sure that ***"public"*** folder exists in the root directory. This was my case.

Comment: I did make sure I had a folder called public and all the required files like html files, Javascript files, Node Server files, css folder... all in one folder like you said. made the changes as you described it in your answer and still it is not working for me.

Comment: @ThN can you send me a link to project or smth, so I can take a look?

Comment: Hi, I had already figured out my mistake. It was because I had placed all the files including the node server within the same folder (public). Once I rearranged the files to their proper places, it works now. Thank you, M22.

Comment: @ThN I am glad you figured out yourself, just in case, this is how my projects look like typicaly: https://ibb.co/jZ19LVL

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. But I found out that it has to do with using the right directory for your style.css file. So I tried this line of code below and it worked perfectly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/scss/style.css">
```

Comment: I tried this answer as well, but I can't get it work at all.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for me was changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/matrix.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/matrix.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried and this did not work for me at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I was able to fix the problem with the tip from Kirankumar Gonti.

Use the following line:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Make sure to set the const path.

You also want to make sure your css folder is nested inside a public folder.

Comment: I tried your answer as well and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I was able to fix the problem with the tip from Kirankumar Gonti.

I used the following line of code in my app.js file, I didn't have a public folder but had my style.css stored in a css folder:

```
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "css")));
```

In my /css/style.css file I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this error I was able to solve it by including "src/assets" in my angular.json file

`"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/upload.php"]`

also the directory of your index.html should not be included in the assets. meaning you should not include "src" in "assets"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue, after some looking around I figured out that you need to only reference the file inside a specific folder and not the whole directory.
example if you are referencing public root inside static `app.use(express.static(`public`))  then you only need to ref` <link rel=`stylesheet` href =`css/styles.css`> and not the whole directory.

Comment: Hi, are you sure? Your solution makes really a change in express headers?

Comment: the files need to be inside public folder which static middleware looks for by default.

Answer (score 0):

***"CSS file blocked: MIME type mismatch"* while using VS Code + Live server**

If you are getting this error while testing using [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) (or an alternative) in VS Code, it may seem that the extension is sending a bad mime type together with the CSS files, when in fact it is sending a 404 error, correctly, in case you have a VS Code workplace top level directory setup incorrectly and thus resources can't be reached
Typically, if your workplace root is set to a dir above the root dir of the actual app, this might easily go unnoticed in VS Code when coding, but the resources are referenced incorrectly during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, but what really works for me is as follows.
If you are using bundling tools mostly they generate their bundle output, like
main.34343.js, I just renamed main.34343.js to main.js, I tried to access main.34343.js via my browser and inspected the response, which I found out as a  404 error, after renaming everything works.
I registered express static middleware  as below.

```js
app.use("/",express.static(_dirname+"./public"))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It can throw the error if you're not using type attribute in your link/script tag.so make sure you are using it.

```
<script defer src="./index.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had jumbled up the code blocks below in reverse order so I was getting this error. If you have this issue, follow the below order and it might help

1.

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

2.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

3.

```
app.use('/api', cors(corsOptions), indexRouter);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what happened at me,
My site was archieved, so the css and js files are not available. After restore my webhost everything goes well.

So, please check are the URLs is correct or not.