# Leaflet markercluster plugin not loading

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a heck of a time getting plugins to load in leaflet. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The files are on my local machine and are included in the html file but I still receive these two errors.

> Loading failed for the  with source
> “.../Plugins/cluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js”.
>
> TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function index.js:15:17

Im assuming the type error is from the plugin not loading...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--LOADS leaflet.js FROM CDN-->
    <script 
        src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin="">
    </script>    
    <!--LOADS leaflet.css FROM CDN-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <!--LOADS style_blank.css FOR LEAFLET-->
    <link href="style_blank.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--LOADS jquery-3.4.1.js FROM CDN-->
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>    
    <!--LOADS markercluster css-->
    <link href="Plugins/cluster/MarkerCluster.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Plugins/cluster/MarkerCluster.Default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--LOADS markercluster plugin-->
    <script src="Plugins/cluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!--CONTAINS GEOJSON DATA-->
    <script src="Data/activeShops.js"></script>
    <!--LOADS LEAFLET MAP DATA/CUSTIMIZATION-->
    <script src="index.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// starting location
var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [41.05, -77.5],
    zoom: 8,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
});

// tile layer
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: ""
}).addTo(map);

// markercluster plugin
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var activeShops = L.geoJSON(activeShops);

markers.addLayer(activeShops);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Are there any problems with my HTML or Javascript file that would prevent this plugin from loading? I have both .css files and javascript src file indluded in HTML as per the directions on github. Thank you.

Comment: You could try loading Leaflet.markercluster files from unpkg CDN as well: https://unpkg.com/browse/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/

Comment: I tried that before and received this error "The resource from “https://unpkg.com/browse/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

Comment: The previous link is just for you to see what files are available, not what you should use as value of your href and src attributes...

Comment: Still gives me the same error. No idea why this isn't working. Currently have the script in the header like this  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>`

Comment: I guess unpkg could be more explicit how you should use it... Compare with the value you used for Leaflet. Use the "view raw" button on unpkg page. `https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem..

the reason is that you load the leafletjs files from the leatflet repo, and this sends `Content-Type: text/html` for this files.
And this server sends a `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header too.

The result is that your browser discovers that you try to load JavaScript and Css, but the content-type of the files behind the Url is not matching what makes your browser blocking this files from loading.

@see [Mozilla developer docs - X-Content-Type-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)

The problem is, you must be on the server side of the loaded files to change the output headers.

The only "hack" to handle this behavoir I found in the question [css-file-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119502/2377961)
But removing the `rel` attribute is a very dirty trick and there is no garanty that this will work in the future.

The only "clean" solution would be to download `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css` and host them on your own webspace.

Answer (score 0):

**Plugins/cluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js**

---

Is this file exist in your project?

---

Comment: Yes it does, it's located under the Plugins folder I created

Comment: Loading failed for the with source “.../Plugins/cluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js”.
Looks like can't find the file here