# Using an I-frame on mechanical turk HIT?

Tags: http, mime-types, mechanicalturk

I'd like to host an external website on AMT using an iframe and allow users to answer to respond on the website. However, I get the following error:

The resource from “https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/create/projects/worker-html.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Could this be caused by the use of a rest API (application/json)? If so, is there a way of fixing it or some work around?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: In the console while trying to preview the HIT

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Express to host the external website? This answer seems to have the same error message and recommends a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119502/2601671

Also, the URL `https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/create/projects/worker-html.js` doesn't exist on the MTurk site. Is this a file you expect to have on your server?

Comment: No, I'm not using Express. I'm not sure about the worker-html.js file though. I think it's part of the files React Create-App creates by default, so maybe it has something to do with that. I'll check on my end

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I'm using a PHP server and serving it as a static site. There is however an API running on the server, but it isn't in JS (or use express). It's running on flask