# The resource from "/Styles/Common/bootstrap.min.css" was blocked due to MIME type ("text/css") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML page and some of the functionality is not working as expected. When i try to see console of browser, i can see error is being shown as below. I suspect this could be the issue of why my some of functionality not working. does anyone can help here to solve below issue?

The resource from "/Styles/Common/bootstrap.min.css" was blocked due to MIME type ("text/css") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Comment: I can imagine an HTML 404 error message would generate that error. Click on the `/Styles/Common/bootstrap.min.css` in the network console and look if the headers and content are actually css

Comment: If you're using express, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657829/css-file-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff

Comment: Weird though that the error message says the type was `text/css` – which would be correct for a stylesheet. If the problem was due to a 404 or other HTTP error, you’d usually get `text/html` as content type of the corresponding error document. Is this actually embedded as a _stylesheet_ - or accidentally as a script maybe …?

Comment: @mplugjan : Thanks. it solved my problem. your hint is enough for me to investigate. much appreciated.