# How to specify the path for static files (such as JS, CSS, images etc) in the server code (Node)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, browser

I am working with Node to create a webpage. This webpage will have Javascript files linked to the webpage or HTML file, but every time I try to open my webpage on the remote machine nothing shows up on the remote machine browser. So, after searching online for more information, I learned that you need to let the Node server know where the static files are. So, it can load or serve to the remote machine. For the life of me, I can't get this to work.

I tried this. `app.use(express.static('public');` It didn't work. Then, `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));` Still nothing works.

I looked in the browser's console and I noticed the following errors.

[image]

Any clues or hints will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try unix path format (file: `./` ; directory: `../`) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125522/path-syntax-rules

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Express serving the files without the correct MIME type (e.g. returning the HTTP header `Content-Type` as `text/html` for all files, rather than `application/javascript` for example (more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119502)).

If you have a "type" attribute on your `<script>` tag, you could try removing that.

Alternatively, [as mentioned here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3226#issuecomment-283979763), using `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + 'public'));` should solve the issue with Express returning the wrong headers (with specific path as first argument of that function).

Answer (score 0):

in this post you can find some instrucctions ( in case you haven't read it already):

[How to serve static files](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/)

A basic necessity for most [http servers](http servers) is to be able to serve static files. Thankfully, it is not that hard to do in Node.js. First you [read the file](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs/), then you serve the file. Here is an example of a script that will serve the files in the current directory:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Which as well, will point you tu a github post [Creating a node-static Server](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static#api).