# The resource from “http://localhost:4200/basics.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[Error that console gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIJGx.png)

[Index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opXiO.png)

This is my angular startup project.

Comment: Have you tried moving the file to assets folder and calling it from there?

Comment: Or maybe try like this src="/basics.js" or src="./basics.js". Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657829/css-file-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff