# laravel not load css and javascript file

Tags: laravel

Laravel don't load css files and javascript files in console of the browser some file I'm getting `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` and for other files I'm getting

```
The resource from "https://my-web.com/lv/assets/js/lang/uk.js" was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

the blocked due to MIME type was applied for all files not only that file

the assets file is in public assets

Comment: your javascript file is detected as HTML content. I suspect that the file is invalid thus receiving 404 not found or something.

Comment: but I have the js files and css files in public/assets

Comment: can you access it directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS file blocked: MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657829/css-file-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff)

Comment: yes I can access the files but not from browser

Comment: The way of loading asset files from public folder is `<script src="{{ asset('js/uk.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: @Bulent : that exactly what i'm doing `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: But the error says about a file /lang/uk.js. What is that?

Comment: like there is a file requesting a `uk.js` for language. can you share `app.js`? maybe you forgot to compile when require to another js

Comment: that file apps.js one of the files I have many js files