# Why my jQuery, files are not loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I import jQuery, boostrap in my head like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

I'm trying to use NodeJS and Express like this, I found it on Google

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('main.html', function(err, data) {
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  'Content-Length': data.length
});
res.write(data);
res.end();
});
}).listen(8000);
```

But when my page is loaded, those libs are not loaded. 
I also have some images

```
    <div class="item active">
          <a href="vungtau.html">
          <img src="IntroduceImage/VungTau.jpg" alt="Vũng Tàu">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Vũng Tàu</h3>
            <h4>Lần đầu đi Vũng Tàu bằng xe máy</h4>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

They are not loaded too. This is address: D:\Atom Project\IntroduceImage\VungTau.jpg

Anyone know why? 
It I load it without NodeJS like this file:///D:/Atom%20Project/main.html. They're all loaded.
Please help, Im new to NodeJS.

[image]

Comment: go through express documentation there is express.static to configure root path of application then according to that relative path give the files refrence

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622394/nodejs-express-served-html-file-not-loading-js-file) to include files using NodeJS + Express into your project.

Comment: Thank you, @ManpreetMatharu, compare with your link, and tried some search. I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give file reference path as given in [express.js-staticFile](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

something like,

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static('./'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I have my images stored in the root directory of the server.

Comment: Does it really need "pp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));"? I only use "app.use(express.static('./'));", it works fine

Comment: if you have an external file in public directory so,

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM Welcome

Answer (score 0):

**hint as follows**

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/static/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```

go through this link

```
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
```